# react-native - Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` supplied to `FontAwesomeIcon`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-awesome

My code in `App.js`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faEllipsisV } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faEllipsisV)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ellipsis-v" style={styles.moreOptions} />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    moreOptions: {
        fontSize: 5,
        color: primary,
    },
})
```

Produce following warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` supplied to
>   `FontAwesomeIcon`.
>       in FontAwesomeIcon (at App.js:44)
>       in App (at withExpoRoot.web.js:10)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at registerRootComponent.web.js:6)
>       in RootComponent
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by AppContainer)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by AppContainer)
>       in AppContainer

but there is an style for it here in [font awesome documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome#color-stylesheet-property). How can this be fixed?

BTW the `color` working although has warning but `fontSize` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think `FontAwesomeIcon` is not a RN `Text` component as such, therefore *fontSize* is not an accepted prop.

Use `<FontAwesomeIcon ... size={5}>` instead.

Comment: So `color: 'red'` should not work in style-sheet however it works! So as color works, fontSize should work too. But the second problem is that I want to apply some other styles to `FontAwesomeIcon` but it returns a warning in console: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` supplied to `FontAwesomeIcon`

Answer (score 0):

@kodfire as per the docs and as samuli said, FontAwesome does support stylesheet , but it only accepts color as its params in it, nothing else. If you want to cchange size use `size` rather than passing `fontSize`.

Check the docs [icon docs](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome#color)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


type Props = {}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    color: 'blue'
  }
})

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faCoffee } style={ style.icon } size={32}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

revert in case of any concerns.

Comment: If I consider using `size={5}` instead of `style={{fontSize: 5}}` and using `color="red"` instead of `style={{color: 'red'}}`, but what should I do with other styles I wanna apply to the element? like padding and so on? When I use the `style` prop the warning still existing.

Comment: wrap it with a parent element like View

Comment: It was already working with another element. I wanted to do it with itself.